# Non-blocking client and server sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets

I started to read and learn about "sockets", but I'm looking for a small code-sample written in C for a client and server which will be non-blocking

The code should be able to send input from the client and the server must be able to receive the output in the non-blocking state, both should be in the non-blocking state.

I've read a lot in Google and books, YouTube, but nothing really helped.

This is my server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int sock;
    int addr_len, bytes_read;
    char recv_data[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr , client_addr;


    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);

    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);


    if (bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
             sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    printf("\nUDPServer Waiting for client on port 5000");
    fflush(stdout);

    while (1)
    {

        bytes_read = recvfrom(sock,recv_data,1024,0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);  // <---- Here is the problem


        recv_data[bytes_read] = '\0';

        printf("\n(%s , %d) said : ",inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),
               ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
        printf("%s", recv_data);
        fflush(stdout);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you're asking how to perform I/O on a non-blocking socket. [Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) has been around for a long time; it covers all this and more, with good code samples.

Comment: Hello Bret -  I used the Beej's guide, but coulden't get it.. please help me out with exampel instead..

Comment: Beej's guide is pretty clear, and it has example programs for what you are trying to achieve. Have a look at chapter 7 of the guide. The first code is the client and the second one is the server.

Comment: chapter 7 explains how to use select. perhaps the question is about how to read from a non-blocking socket. That's why I came here

Answer (score 12):

The idea with non-blocking I/O is to be able to handle *multiple* sockets without resorting to multiple threads. The central part here is [*I/O de-multiplexing*](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzab6/rzab6cmultiplex.htm), i.e. a call to [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) or [`poll(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or platform specific functions like [`epoll(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/epoll.7.html) or [`kqueue(2)`](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)).

Here's a brief [introduction](http://www.kegel.com/dkftpbench/nonblocking.html).

Comment: How can i impant "  select() " in my server ?

Comment: Your loop waits in the `select()`, then checks that any of the registered sockets are readable (in an inner loop), then reads from each active socket.

Comment: code exampel please, my english not good

Comment: @user1022734: you are way too lazy. http://www.bing.com/search?q=unix+select+socket+example+plz or just search stackoverflow...

Comment: I gave you a link, that has code. Read.

Comment: What's with the numbers in the function arguments?

Comment: They are the man section in which the man page can be found.

Comment: Actually, i'm just trying to do *other things* and not put the thread to sleep if there's no connections.  Getting a blocking socket up is easy.  Getting a non-blocking one is a real pain.