# How does multithreaded servers work?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I know how to use sockets and multithreading but I wanted to make a chat with one servers and many clients as the server gets a string from every client when he types it and after getting it, sending it to every one of the clients aside from the sender. Simple chat.
I didn't know how to do that because of one question that popped in mind, i want to be able to use `recv` on each client at the same time, but is this how regular chat servers work ? They create a thread for EVERY client ? If I want to do so in my computer then am I limited ? I have all of the program written and I have a dynamic array of clients' structs including IP, port, and a pointer to that socket (which is in a dynamic array of sockets) and I have a dynamic array of `sockaddr_in` structs - EVERYTHING's working and compiling well but I'm not sure how to get the messages of all clients at the same time, do I really need a thread for each client ?

Comment: Question is pretty broad, IMO you should narrow little bit...anyway no, you don't NEED a thread for each client (and number of threads isn't physically limited to number of cores/CPUs). Of course if you serve all requests with one thread then requests will be serialized (client B must wait client A finished to send its data before its request is served). IMO you should use a thread for each REQUEST, it doesn't matter how many clients you have: if they communicate one by one then you'll always need one thread (and threads will increase when you have to serve multiple requests at same moment).

Comment: What makes you think that number of threads is limited to the number of cores? CPUs are fast enough to handle multiple clients per core.

Comment: You're right, my bad, it's not about cores, got confused.
@AdrianoRepetti
But recv waits a certain amount of time, doesn't it ? So I'll have to do a for loop on all of the structs of clients and recv from each sockets ? Won't it wait for each socket to send something ? And if the certain client doesn't send anything but just accepts messages ?

Answer (score 1):

You should realize that server don't have one or multiple big intel xeon processor for no reason. Every request should be handled independently and preferably as fast as possible. On my processor its fine if there are 3700 seperate threads running, but I can imagine that there are even more on a webserver.

Can't you simply loop through the whole array and fix the messages for every client in that way? Because, even if you multithread it, your cpu will run thread after thread and the messages won't be send

Comment: So I should use FOR loop through each socket and recieve ? As far as I've seen 'recv' function waits for something to being sent, is it this way ? Will one thread be enough to recieve from each one ?

Comment: See answer two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195724/non-blocking-client-and-server-sockets-in-c