# linux server with select but client block

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select

I have wrote a programe server  and I want to thousands of clients connect to it at a time , the code is bellow:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/select.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int fds[sizeof(fd_set)*8];

static usage(const char* proc)
{
     printf("usage :%s [local_ip] [local_port]\n",proc);
}

int startup(const char* ip,int port)
{
     int sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
     if(sock < 0)
     {
         perror("socket");
         exit(2);
     }
     int opt = 1;

     setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&opt,sizeof(opt));
     //set non-blocking 
     int flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0);
     fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags|O_NONBLOCK);

     struct sockaddr_in local;
     local.sin_family = AF_INET;
     local.sin_port = htons(port);
     local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

     if(bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&local,sizeof(local)) < 0)
     {
        perror("bind");
        exit(3);
     }

     if(listen(sock,10) < 0)
     {
        perror("listen");
        exit(4);
     }

     return sock;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3)
    {
            usage(argv[0]);
            return 1;
    }
    int listen_sock = startup(argv[1],atoi(argv[2]));
    printf("fd_set: %d\n",sizeof(fd_set)*8);
    int fds[sizeof(fd_set)];
    int nums = sizeof(fds)/sizeof(fds[0]);
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < nums; i++)
    {
            fds[i] = -1;
    }
    fds[0] = listen_sock;
    int maxfd = -1;
    fd_set rfds;//读事件
    fd_set wfds;//写事件

    while(1)
    {
            int maxfd = -1;
            struct timeval timeout = {2,0};
            FD_ZERO(&rfds);
            FD_ZERO(&wfds);
            i = 0;
            for(; i < nums;i++)
            {
                    if(fds[i] == -1)
                    {
                            continue;
                    }
                    FD_SET(fds[i],&rfds);
                    if(maxfd < fds[i])
                    {
                            maxfd = fds[i];
                    }
            }
            switch(select(maxfd+1,&rfds,&wfds,NULL,&timeout))
            {
                    case -1:   //select失败
                            perror("select");
                            break;
                    case 0:    //超过时间没有任何描述符就绪
                            printf("time out!\n");
                            break;
                    default:
                            {
                                    //at least one fd ready!
                                    i = 0;
                                    for(; i < nums;i++)
                                    {
                                            if(i == 0 && FD_ISSET(fds[i],&rfds))//listen_sock is ready, get connect
                                            {
                                                    struct sockaddr_in client;
                                                    socklen_t len = sizeof(client);
                                                    int new_sock = accept(listen_sock,(struct sockaddr*)&client,&len);
                                                    if(new_sock < 0)
                                                    {
                                                       perror("accept");
                                                       continue;
                                                    }

                                                    printf("get a new client: [%s:%d]\n",inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr),ntohs(client.sin_port));
                                                    int flags = fcntl(new_sock, F_GETFL, 0);
                                                    fcntl(new_sock, F_SETFL, flags|O_NONBLOCK);
                                                    int j = 1;
                                                    for(; j < nums ; j++)
                                                    {
                                                            if(fds[j] == -1)
                                                            {
                                                                    break;
                                                            }
                                                    }

                                                   if(j == nums)
                                                   {
                                                            close(new_sock);
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                            fds[j] = new_sock;
                                                    }
                                            }


                                            else if(i != 0 && FD_ISSET(fds[i],&rfds))//normal fd is ready
                                            {
                                                    char buf[1024];
                                                    ssize_t s = read(fds[i],buf,sizeof(buf)-1);
                                                    if( s > 0)
                                                    {
                                                            buf[s] = 0;
                                                            printf("client# %s\n",buf);
                                                            FD_SET(fds[i],&wfds);

                                                    }
                                                    else if(s == 0)
                                                    {
                                                            printf("client is quit！\n");
                                                            close(fds[i]);
                                                            fds[i] = -1;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                            perror("read");
                                                            close(fds[i]);
                                                            fds[i] = -1;
                                                    }
                                            }
                                            if(i !=0 && FD_ISSET(fds[i],&wfds))//普通的写操作
                                            {
                                                    const char* msg = "hello client!\n";
                                                    ssize_t s = write(fds[i],msg,strlen(msg));
                                                    if(s < 0)
                                                    {
                                                            perror("write");
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                            FD_CLR(fds[i],&wfds);
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
            }

    }
    close(listen_sock);
    return 0;
}
```

In the code, I have set non-blocking when I accept a new socket, But when I test it with ab, it shows result below:

```
[zoushengfu@test ~]$ ab -n 10 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:1234/ 
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1430300 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/ Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)...
apr_pollset_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
```

And server shows:

[image]

The result seem to mean client block, how to slove it or give some examples for me?

Comment: Take a look in this [Non-lbocking client and server sockets in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195724/non-blocking-client-and-server-sockets-in-c)

Comment: Please do not post images of text, it makes it difficult for people to both search and copy-paste to try to help you. Please edit your question with the text (formatted as code preferably) instead of the image. Good luck.

Comment: OK, I will modify it

Comment: I use ApacheBench as the client, result  is  related to client

Comment: The *server response* is still an image

Comment: And what is the problem? Client has connected and sent the request, you have got the request and sent him your (non HTTP compliant) answer. If you want to see the answer in client software, you shall send a http formatted answer and ensure it is whole sent by server's non-blocking writes.

Comment: Ok. I see, thank you

Comment: How to ensure it is whole sent by server's non-blocking writes? set socket? such as:`int flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0);
     fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags|O_NONBLOCK);`

Comment: If you read the documentation of `write` you can see that `write` can send less then the whole buffer. In such case you shall call it again with the remaining part. This is why `write` is usually used in a loop. Maybe in your case you can use normal blocking sockets for `read` and `write` instead of non-blocking, `select` is sufficient to avoid blocking.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should bind your server to INADDR_ANY rather than a specific IP address, and you may have to take care of firewall rules and port forwarding as well.
2. This is wrong:

   ```
   maxfd = fds[i];
   ```

   The first parameter to `select()` is not `maxfd` but `nfds`, the *number* of active `fd`s, and it should have been set above to the largest valid `i+1`, so as to include the entry at `fds[0]` for the listening socket.

Comment: Don't forget to change the prior test as well.

Comment: How to modify it ? I can not understand you

Comment: Yes, I have add +1 at `select(maxfd+1, &rfds, &wfds, NULL, NULL)`

Comment: Please read what I wrote again, or even just the documentation in *man select*. Your `maxfd` variable is fundamentally misconceived and indeed misnamed.

Comment: Sorry, I am Chinese and is not goog at English. Maybe have some troubles in English

Comment: Then I don't see how I can help you short of rewriting all the code for you, which would teach you nothing. I suggest you look at some C networking tutorials.

Comment: I am afraid that You are not right with the meaning of the first argument of `select`. As per the man page:  "nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1". This part of OP's code is O.K.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in the code was that it did not send a http formatted answer. The answer has to contain http headers to be accepted by browsers.

Another problem which would appear if your server answers a longer string is that `write` does not need to send the whole buffer at once. This can be solved by memorizing how many bytes of the answer string was sent to the given socket. In the following code I do it with the array `fdsi`.

The final modification I'd do is to use normal blocking sockets for client's connections. This is a question of taste, but I think that `select` is sufficient to avoid blocking of your program.

The resulting code with those minimal improvements is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/select.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>

char* msg = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Length: 82\r\n\r\n<html><head><title>An Example Page</title></head><body>Hello client</body></html>\n";
int fds[sizeof(fd_set)*8];
int fdsi[sizeof(fd_set)*8];

static usage(const char* proc)
{
     printf("usage :%s [local_ip] [local_port]\n",proc);
}

int startup(const char* ip,int port)
{
     int sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
     if(sock < 0)
     {
         perror("socket");
         exit(2);
     }
     int opt = 1;

     setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&opt,sizeof(opt));
     //set non-blocking 
     int flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0);
     fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags|O_NONBLOCK);

     struct sockaddr_in local;
     local.sin_family = AF_INET;
     local.sin_port = htons(port);
     local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

     if(bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&local,sizeof(local)) < 0)
     {
        perror("bind");
        exit(3);
     }

     if(listen(sock,10) < 0)
     {
        perror("listen");
        exit(4);
     }

     return sock;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3)
    {
            usage(argv[0]);
            return 1;
    }
    int listen_sock = startup(argv[1],atoi(argv[2]));
    printf("fd_set: %d\n",sizeof(fd_set)*8);
    int fds[sizeof(fd_set)];
    int nums = sizeof(fds)/sizeof(fds[0]);
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < nums; i++)
    {
            fds[i] = -1;
    }
    fds[0] = listen_sock;
    int maxfd = -1;
    fd_set rfds;//读事件
    fd_set wfds;//写事件

    while(1)
    {
            int maxfd = -1;
            struct timeval timeout = {2,0};
            FD_ZERO(&rfds);
            FD_ZERO(&wfds);
            i = 0;
            for(; i < nums;i++)
            {
                    if(fds[i] == -1)
                    {
                            continue;
                    }
                    FD_SET(fds[i],&rfds);
                    if(maxfd < fds[i])
                    {
                            maxfd = fds[i];
                    }
            }
            switch(select(maxfd+1,&rfds,&wfds,NULL,&timeout))
            {
                    case -1:   //select失败
                            perror("select");
                            break;
                    case 0:    //超过时间没有任何描述符就绪
                            printf("time out!\n");
                            break;
                    default:
                            {
                                    //at least one fd ready!
                                    i = 0;
                                    for(; i < nums;i++)
                                    {
                                            if(i == 0 && FD_ISSET(fds[i],&rfds))//listen_sock is ready, get connect
                                            {
                                                    struct sockaddr_in client;
                                                    socklen_t len = sizeof(client);
                                                    int new_sock = accept(listen_sock,(struct sockaddr*)&client,&len);
                                                    if(new_sock < 0)
                                                    {
                                                       perror("accept");
                                                       continue;
                                                    }

                                                    printf("get a new client: [%s:%d]\n",inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr),ntohs(client.sin_port));
                                                    //int flags = fcntl(new_sock, F_GETFL, 0);
                                                    //fcntl(new_sock, F_SETFL, flags|O_NONBLOCK);
                                                    int j = 1;
                                                    for(; j < nums ; j++)
                                                    {
                                                            if(fds[j] == -1)
                                                            {
                                                                    break;
                                                            }
                                                    }

                                                   if(j == nums)
                                                   {
                                                            close(new_sock);
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                            fds[j] = new_sock;
                                                            fdsi[j] = 0;
                                                    }
                                            }


                                            else if(i != 0 && FD_ISSET(fds[i],&rfds))//normal fd is ready
                                            {
                                                    char buf[1024];
                                                    ssize_t s = read(fds[i],buf,sizeof(buf)-1);
                                                    if( s > 0)
                                                    {
                                                            buf[s] = 0;
                                                            printf("client# %s\n",buf);
                                                            FD_SET(fds[i],&wfds);

                                                    }
                                                    else if(s == 0)
                                                    {
                                                            printf("client is quit！\n");
                                                            close(fds[i]);
                                                            fds[i] = -1;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                            perror("read");
                                                            close(fds[i]);
                                                            fds[i] = -1;
                                                    }
                                            }
                                            if(i !=0 && FD_ISSET(fds[i],&wfds))//普通的写操作
                                            {
                                                    ssize_t s = write(fds[i],msg+fdsi[i],strlen(msg)-fdsi[i]);
                                                    if(s < 0)
                                                    {
                                                            perror("write");
                                                    } else {
                                                        fdsi[i] += s;
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
            }

    }
    close(listen_sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the core of your code there's an issue of design.

Your purpose is to have thousands of concurrent connections and you're using `select` to achieve this.

However, on many system `select` will be limited to a smaller number of clients (or max `fd` values).

On Unix the limit was set (historically) at an `fd==1023` (any greater value would break the `select` call in weird and unexpected ways) and Windows used to have a limit set at 63 `fd`s per set.

Many implementations still have these limits and special code is required to circumvent these issues (notice [the BUGs section on Linux's `man` page for `select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html#BUGS)).

Also, `select` performs poorly on "thousands" of connections (which is what you're aiming for).

You will have to look into OS specific approaches (`epoll` on Linux, `kqueue` on macOS/BSD, etc') in order to reach "thousands" of concurrent connections.

There are libraries that abstract these system calls and allow you to write system independent code. These come in flavors and sizes, so you'll have to decide which one you prefer.